# dragging items based on percentage to containment element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Here is what it looks like;

```
$( "#box ul li" ).draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});
$( ".item" ).draggable({containment: ".door"});

$( ".door" ).droppable({
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper, .item)",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "<div class='item'></div>" ).html(ui.draggable.find("img")).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

User drags the $( "#box ul li" ) element and drops it on $(".door") element. And it appends it to $(".door") element with $(".item") selector.

I am using jquery UI - Draggable to drag and drop items. There is no problem there.

**Here is the actual question;**

But when you start dragging the element, the function changes the element's left and top positions like; **top:10px left:10px**.
But i want to drag the item based on percentage to the containment element. It should be
**top:10%; left:10%**.

any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 25):

I've found a solution;

```
$( ".item" ).draggable({
  containment: ".door",
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
   $(this).css("left",parseInt($(this).css("left")) / ($(".door").width() / 100)+"%");
   $(this).css("top",parseInt($(this).css("top")) / ($(".door").height() / 100)+"%");
  }
});
```

Comment: @RecepSimsek  I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880510/constantly-move-resizable-draggable-image-on-the-video-when-the-browser-is-resiz?noredirect=1#comment92674974_52880510). I am wondering if you can give me some pointers

Answer (score 5):

Try this Code :

```
$( ".element" ).draggable({

    stop: function (){
     var l = ( 100 * parseFloat($(this).css("left")) / parseFloat($(this).parent().css("width")) )+ "%" ;
     var t = ( 100 * parseFloat($(this).css("top")) / parseFloat($(this).parent().css("height")) )+ "%" ;
     $(this).css("left" , l);
     $(this).css("top" , t);
     }

});
```

Answer (score 5):

Little bit updated version of all above:

```
$('.element').draggable({
    containment: 'parent',
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $elm = $(this);
        var pos = $elm.position(),
            parentSizes = {
                height: $elm.parent().height(),
                width: $elm.parent().width()
            };

        $elm.css('top', ((pos.top/parentSizes.height) * 100) + '%').css('left', ((pos.left/parentSizes.width) * 100) + '%');
}});
```