# Element goes way off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a **fixed** `div` which I made draggable through `JQuery UI`. The `div` is centered on startup.

The problem is, when the `div` gets dragged off screen, (meaning, because it goes off screen, the page starts scrolling,) the `div` goes way over to the side. The more you drag, the more it goes away from the cursor.

Also, how can I position the `div` with percentage, this way when the browser gets resized, the `div` will maintain its position? (Even after it gets dragged.)

#### JSFiddle

```js
var dragDiv = $('#draggable');

dragDiv.css({
  'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - (dragDiv.outerHeight() / 2),
  'left': ($(window).width() / 2) - (dragDiv.outerWidth() / 2)
});

dragDiv.draggable();
```

```css
body {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: url("http://www.freevector.com/site_media/preview_images/FreeVector-Square-Patterns-Set.jpg");
}
#draggable {
  color: lightblue;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="draggable">Drag Me!</div>
```

Comment: Try `position:absolute;` , and what do you mean by the div will maintain its position ?

Comment: But I need `position: fixed` because I want the `div` to stay in its position when you scroll.

Comment: What I mean by maintain its position, is I want it to stay on screen even if you resize the browser.

Comment: Sorry about that... I didn't fully grok what you were trying to do at first, but I took another stab at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a fixed position overlay/wrapper:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vptuzcek/2/)**

```js
var dragDiv = $('#draggable');

dragDiv.css({
  'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - (dragDiv.outerHeight() / 2),
  'left': ($(window).width() / 2) - (dragDiv.outerWidth() / 2)
});

dragDiv.draggable({
  containment: "parent" // <- keep draggable within fixed overlay
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: url("http://www.freevector.com/site_media/preview_images/FreeVector-Square-Patterns-Set.jpg");
}
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}
#draggable {
  color: lightblue;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="fixed">fixed overlay<!-- add fixed position overlay/wrapper -->
  <div id="draggable">Drag Me!</div>
</div>
```

---

As for setting the position in percent, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11117305/1947286).

Comment: Thanks Really like the answer, and the link! The only problem is, onstartup, before the `div` actually drags, it isn't in percentage values. How can I make `draggable` into a percentage value on startup?

Comment: Also, is it important to have `position: absolute` for `draggable`?

Comment: @Jessica as far as I can tell the only way to force jQuery UI's Draggable to use percent rather than pixels would be to edit the jQuery UI core. I would strongly advise against that, or if you decide to do it, document it thoroughly, so the next developer knows that they're not working with the default functionality.

Comment: @Jessica It looks like relative and absolute positioning will work, it just bugs out on fixed positioning.